# Como usar find no resultado de find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Quando executo um `find_all`, depois não consigo usar `find` no resultado deste.
Exemplo:

```
anuncios = soup.find_all('div', class_='txt-value')

anuncios.find('p', class_='well') # Erro!
```

Mas se eu não usar `find_all`, e em vez disso usar `find`, aí funciona:

```
anuncios = soup.find('div', class_='txt-value')

anuncios.find('p', class_='well') # não dá erro
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) retorna uma lista de elementos, mas [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) só pode ser chamado a partir de um elemento.

E como `find` só retorna um único elemento, é por isso que o segundo código funciona (o primeiro `find` busca por uma `div`, e a partir dela você faz outro `find`).

O detalhe é que `find` vai retornar o primeiro elemento que for encontrado. No seu caso, por exemplo, se tiver duas `div`'s cuja classe é `txt-value`, `soup.find('div', class_='txt-value')` vai retornar a primeira delas.

Já com `find_all` você tem uma lista de todas as `div`'s, e pode procurar o `p` a partir delas:

```
html = '''
<div id="a1" class="txt-value"><p class="well">bla1</p></div>
<div id="a2" class="txt-value"><p class="well">bla2</p></div>
<div id="a3" class="txt-value"><p class="well">bla3</p></div>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# buscar todas as div's
for anuncio in soup.find_all('div', class_='txt-value'):
    # para cada div, procuro o "p"
    p = anuncio.find('p', class_='well')
    print('encontrei: ', p)

# procuro somente a primeira div que tenha class-"txt-value"
anuncio = soup.find('div', class_='txt-value')
# dentro desta div procuro o "p"
p = anuncio.find('p', class_='well')
print('p dentro da primeira div:', p)
```

A saída do código acima é:

```
encontrei:  <p class="well">bla1</p>
encontrei:  <p class="well">bla2</p>
encontrei:  <p class="well">bla3</p>
p dentro da primeira div: <p class="well">bla1</p>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, ótima resposta!

Comment: Entendi
entao a forma de buscar elementos depois de um find_all é passar um for